# r: sampling within groups, matching subgroup sizes

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, sample

I have a very unbalanced dataset, containing multiple groups, each divided into to two types of observations.
Here's a synthetic example of the structure (actual data contains hundreds of groups and millions of observations):

```
df <- data.frame(
  group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  1, 1,    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,  2, 2, 2),
  type  = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  1, 1,    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  1, 1, 1),
  value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,  6, 7,    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,  7, 8, 9)
)
```

I need to compare the standard deviation of each type, within each group. Something like that:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(group, type) %>%
  ## something is missing here...
  summarise(n    = n(), 
            mean = mean(value))
```

However, the number of observation of each type is unbalanced, and this can bias the comparison.

I thought to reduce the number of "type 0" observation by way of sampling them, to match the number of "type 1" observation for each group.
I found some suggestions to use `slice_sample()` but couldn't get it to work with this situation of group-type matching...

How can I sample from each pool of group+type0 observations, matching the size of each corresponding group+type1 pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply run `filter` instead of `slice_sample` like below

```
df %>%
    filter(
        row_number() %in% c(sample(which(!type), sum(type)), which(type == 1)),
        .by = group
    )
```

which gives, for example

```
   group type value
1      1    0     3
2      1    0     5
3      1    1     6
4      1    1     7
5      2    0     1
6      2    0     2
7      2    0     4
8      2    1     7
9      2    1     8
10     2    1     9
```

Comment: This gives equal Ns, but doesnwt *sample*. It simply takes the first n lines for each group. right?

Comment: @BoTz no, the rows are sampled

Comment: This solution uses the actual values of 0 and 1, and assumes that type is always the bigger group and always sorted first. some alterations should be made to adapt to other cases...  However, this is the shortest and most elegant approach so i accept it

Comment: @BoTz yes, your understanding is right.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  tidyr::nest() %>% 
  mutate(data = lapply(data, function(i) {
    type <- i$type
    ones_n <- length(type[type == 1])
    zeros <- type[type == 0]
    sampled_obs <- sample(seq_len(length(zeros)), size = ones_n)
    sampled_zeros <- seq_len(length(zeros)) %in% sampled_obs
    take_this <- rep(TRUE, length(type))
    take_this[type == 1] <- TRUE
    take_this[type == 0] <- sampled_zeros
    i$take_this <- take_this
    i
  })) %>% 
  tidyr::unnest(data) %>% 
  filter(take_this)
```

Here I use nesting which allows for custom operations inside each group. I couldn't make `sample_slice` working, I used `slice` instead. The idea is to mark every observation with `take_this = TRUE/FALSE`. If the index of a zero row is sampled then it's taken.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a somewhat inelegant approach, but should accomplish this. First, I created a variable that determines the number of samples based on the minimum number of observations when grouped by `group` and `type`. This part uses `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(nmax = max(row_number()), .by = c(group, type)) %>%
  mutate(sample_n = min(nmax), .by = group) %>% select(-nmax)
```

This creates a temporary variable `sample_n` that tells us what the minimum number of observations the smallest group contains, per `group`. Here we should have 2 for `group == 1` and 3 for `group == 2` since group sizes of `type == 1` was 2 and 3, respectively:

```
# unique(df2[, c("group", "sample_n")])
#   group sample_n
# 1     1        2
# 8     2        3
```

Then in base R we can use `split` and `sample` with `lapply`:

```
set.seed(123)
ll <- lapply(split(df2, ~ df2$group + df2$type), 
             function(x) x[sample(nrow(x), max(x$sample_n)), -4])
```

Then combine with `do.call`:

```
df_final <- do.call(rbind, ll)
df_final <- df_final[order(df_final$group),]
```

All together with output:

```
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(nmax = max(row_number()), .by = c(group, type)) %>%
  mutate(sample_n = min(nmax), .by = group) %>% select(-nmax)
ll <- lapply(split(df2, ~ df2$group + df2$type), 
             function(x) x[sample(nrow(x), max(x$sample_n)), -4])
df_final <- do.call(rbind, ll)
df_final <- df_final[order(df_final$group),]

#       group type value
#1.0.3      1    0     3
#1.0.2      1    0     2
#1.1.7      1    1     7
#1.1.6      1    1     6
#2.0.10     2    0     3
#2.0.9      2    0     2
#2.0.12     2    0     5
#2.1.14     2    1     7
#2.1.15     2    1     8
#2.1.16     2    1     9
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative with slightly less code

```
set.seed(123)
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(size = sum(type)) %>%
  filter(type == 0) %>%
  slice(sample.int(n(), size = size[1L])) %>%
  bind_rows(filter(df, type == 1))
# A tibble: 10 × 4
# Groups:   group [2]
   group  type value  size
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     0     3     2
 2     1     0     2     2
 3     2     0     3     3
 4     2     0     2     3
 5     2     0     5     3
 6     1     1     6    NA
 7     1     1     7    NA
 8     2     1     7    NA
 9     2     1     8    NA
10     2     1     9    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

I've generalized [ThomasIsCoding](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12158757/thomasiscoding)'s answer, and avoided the assumptions that are true for the example data, but false otherwise.

This is also the approach I used at the end:

```
df %>% 
  arrange(group, type) %>%
  filter(row_number() %in% c(sample(which(type == 0),
                                    sum(type == 1)),
                             which(type == 1)),
         .by = group) %>%
  group_by(group, type) %>%
  summarise(n    = n(), 
            mean = mean(value))
```